# Python convert date to datetime

Tags: python

I have following string of date `"2018-05-08"` and I would like to convert it into the datetime format of python like: `"2018-05-08T00:00:00.0000000"`. I understand I can combine the string like:

```
> date = "2018-05-08"
> time = "T00:00:00.0000000"
> date+time
'2018-05-08T00:00:00.0000000'
```

But is there pythonic way of doing it where I can use libraries like datetime?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `datetime` module like this example:

```
import datetime 

date = "2018-05-08"
final = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
print(final)
```

Output:

```
2018-05-08T00:00:00.000000
```

For more details visit `datetime`'s [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
d = date.today()
datetime.combine(d, datetime.min.time())
```

Comment: `import date_converter
my_datetime = date_converter.date_to_datetime(my_date)`

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime 
datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime('2018-05-08','%Y-%m-%d'),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

OUTPUT:

```
'2018-05-08T00:00:00.000000'
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from datetime import datetime
date_as_datetime = datetime.strptime("2018-05-08", '%Y-%m-%d')
date_as_string = date_as_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

print(date_as_string)
```

Out:

```
'2018-05-08T00:00:00'
```

See strptime/strftime options here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the datetime module and the strftime method from that module. Here is an example below if we want to format the current time.

```
import datetime

current_time = datetime.datetime.now()

formatted_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(current_time, "%Y-%h-%d %H:%m:%S")
print(formatted_time)
```

Here is the output:

```
2018-May-08 13:05:16
```